# How to replace the nth word of a search result in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have text lines in Notepad++ like below:

```
dog cat duck fan dog donkey
```

I want to replace the second occurrence of the word 'dog' with 'peacock' just like below.

```
dog cat duck fan peacock donkey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with so-called [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), see below. I'm not sure if you're familiar with them, but the regular expression `(dog.*)(dog)` will match all lines where the word 'dog' appears twice, and with `$1peacock` you replace the find result with the first part of the match (`dog.*`) followed by `peacock`. Make sure to set the Search Mode at the bottom of the dialog to 'Regular expression'.

[image]

This will produce the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it the nth word or second occurence of a word to replace?

For the former use a regular expression like this

Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for the replace window.

In Find what: `^(([^ ]+ ){4})([^ ]+ )(.*)`
Replace with: `$1peacock$3`
Uncheck all boxes and select radio button Regular expression

To explain the RegEx:

- `^` anchors at line begin, `$` at line end
- `()` build a capture group
- `([^ ]+ )` the `[]` denote a class, the `^` inside means a negated class, so this means - not a space, the `+` gathers at least one but as much as possible. followed by a space. In total this will match the first word.
- the following `{4}` gets 4 words and as this is enclosed with another set of parentheses this capture group gets the first four words
- the next word and space is the one to replace`([^ ]+ )` followed by the rest of the line `(.*)$`
- The replace reinserts the first (nested) group with `$1` the replacement  `peacock` and the remainder of the line `$3` tossing the 5th word `$2`